# How to convey the idea of 'each of more than one person saying a different thing'?

Tags: sentence

I am a non-native English speaker. I have a question about forming the following sentence:

> "One one person is saying one one thing."

I mean each person is saying a different thing.

I want to express this angrily.

Is the sentence correctly formed?

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Unfortunately, this is not a writers workshop or proofreading service, and our question-and-answer format is not well-suited to providing editorial advice. Like our sister site for [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), we are equipped to answer specific questions you have about grammar or usage. Please take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Comment: @choster These 'Unfortunately ...' responses are developing into a stylish sub-genre.

Comment: English doesn't allow duplicating determinatives like "one one".  How many people are you talking about?  For two, you might use *one person* an *the other*.  For more than two, there's nothing wrong with your phrasing *each person is saying a different thing*.  English verbs don't have an anger aspect, so if you're angry about the situation, you'll have to say so.

Comment: If what you *mean* is *each person is saying a different thing* (perfectly normal English), why not just say that? I don't see how this meaningfully represents a "real-world problem" for which you need help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't reflect a real-world problem.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's probably close-worthy, but what makes you think it doesn't reflect a real-world problem, and if it doesn't, why is that an issue?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I agree.  I give choster's comment an 8.  It's got a good tune but doesn't have enough contempt so that you can dance to it.

Comment: @deadrat: Putting aside the fact that this OP should probably be using [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), it's obvious that he *does* know how to express what he wants to say in valid English. I simply don't see the point of asking or answering questions about whether an almost random sequence of words is "grammatical", when there's not the slightest reason to suppose it *would* be.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It's an odd post.  No native speaker would say "one one", but his "I mean" is perfectly fluent.  The OP doesn't quite ask whether something is "grammatical", and his request hardly seems "random" words.  But I was wondering about the "real world" requirement.  Does that mean no hypotheticals?

Comment: @deadrat: I'm sure our FAQ *used* to include the requirement that questions should reflect *actual, real-world problems*, but I can't find that now. Nevertheless, even if the actual *text* has changed, I doubt the *reason* has. But I do note that the *What types of questions should I avoid asking* section says it's adapted from one containing the stricture [*(Avoid asking) questions with no problem to be solved or where the problem is some variant of "I'm curious if other people feel like I do"*](http://faq.metafilter.com/tags/chatfilter)

Comment: The question seems to be how to differentiate between the statement of fact "Each person is saying something different" and the communication of frustration with that fact, as in "Every single person is saying something different" or similar. Seems like a valid question to me.

Comment: I can rewrite the question to reflect that question, if that is the right way to handle this. I don't know protocol around here for things like that.

Comment: @FumbleFingers What do you think?

Comment: @GetzelR: I think if there *is* a "real-world problem" for OP here, it can only be because in *his* native language there's some contextually-related construction where the equivalent of *One one person* does indeed convey emphasis, anger, or some such. In which case the question might very well be more than welcome on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), since it would then make sense, and could be extremely useful to *others* who might otherwise be tempted to assume it makes sense in English too. That's all I can think of to say about it.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Can't it be read (and maybe clearly rewritten) as "How does one add the emphasis/anger to the statement of fact?" As evidenced by the single (accepted) answer, this scenario may have people reaching for emojis when there is a verbal combination available...

Comment: @GetzelR: I'm sure there are many "vaguely-related" questions in this general area that I wouldn't closevote (or vote to migrate, in the unconfirmed scenario I suggested). But the question is what it is, and must be assessed as such. As to the "accepted answer", I think it does ELU no favours to have an "endorsed" answer apparently claiming that *there isn't anything incorrect with [OP's nonsense text]*. Nor do I think much of the gratuitous aside *English is a bit emotionally retarded*. Both the question and the answer are complete drivel, imho.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you are looking for the sentence 
*each person is saying a different thing* (anger emoji)
since there isn't anything incorrect with your sentence and English is a bit emotionally retarded

Comment: It seems to me that the original poster is looking for "Every single person is saying something different" or something to that effect.